# font size not applied in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, font-size

This is driving me mad...

I was doing my asp.net sandbox website when out of the blue I start to realize that in IE8 (IE7 compatible view or not) does not show CSS font proper...

in the image below **I removed all CSS** and **add only one**:

```
body {
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

and this is (sadly) the **result**:

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-06-08_0927_iefont.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-06-08_0927_iefont.png)

Is there any soul willing to help me...? this is driving me mad since saturday night! I can't find a proper solution, I really thought is was something with CSS, so I even validate all CSS through [CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) and [validate](http://validator.w3.org/) all the page...

nothing changed a bit of the result :(

All the help, or even a blow in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

**P.S.** both [Opera](http://www.Opera.com) and [Chrome](http://Chrome.google.com) as well [Safari](http://www.apple.com/Safari) display the same result as [FF](http://www.getfirefox.com), the right result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the text is inside a table (as I see in your screenshots) try:

```
body, td {
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

Comment: Wow... so simple ... do you care to explain why do I need to add the TableDefinition as well, the body should be the larger scoop right?

Comment: I have never known exactly why, but I've always had this problem (among many others) with IE. Search Google for "internet explorer td doesn't inherit body" and you'll get many results but not any useful answer

Comment: No, never understood "why" myself. My theory is that the element hierarchy in trident is essentially broken and supported by buggy hack cross references to get the cascading. This would explain why forms, tables, and select boxes often have strange out-of-flow type bugs. One of these days I'll decompile IE and find out :P

Comment: grrr to IE... even showing a normal icon is not possible... what a waste of time on creating IE8... Thank you very much Victor!

Answer (score 2):

i think what Victor suggested should work.  Also, next time you can try

```
* { font-size: 11px }
```

as a test.  Obviously you don't want to alter other elements such as h1, h2, etc for their font sizes, but you can use the line above to try things out, so that you can guess that if the line above works, then maybe you need to specify font-size for an additional tag besides the body you originally specified.

Comment: * is a bit of a brutal solution imho

Comment: oh it is merely to use it as a debug / test situation in this case.